# Reentrant StampedLock

Tags: java, multithreading, stampedlock

Is there a reentrant implementation of `StampedLock`?

Specifically, I want the implementation to be smart enough to use an existing write-lock when I invoke a method that expects (and tries to acquire) a read-lock.

Why a reentrant implementation? I find the resulting code easier to read and less error-prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my personal attempt at solving this problem. I hope you find it helpful.

ReentrantStampedLock:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock;

/**
 * A reentrant implementation of a StampedLock that can be used with try-with-resources.
 */
public final class ReentrantStampedLock
{
    private static void doNotUnlock()
    {
    }

    // Excellent overview of StampedLock:
    // https://www.javaspecialists.eu/talks/pdfs/2014%20JavaLand%20in%20Germany%20-%20%22Java%208%20From%20Smile%20To%20Tears%20-%20Emotional%20StampedLock%22%20by%20Heinz%20Kabutz.pdf
    private final StampedLock lock = new StampedLock();

    /**
     * The stamp associated with the current thread. {@code null} if none.
     */
    private final ThreadLocal<Long> stamp = new ThreadLocal<>();

    /**
     * Creates a new lock.
     */
    public ReentrantStampedLock()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @return true if the caller is holding an optimistic read-lock
     */
    public boolean isOptimisticRead()
    {
        Long existingStamp = this.stamp.get();
        return existingStamp != null && StampedLock.isOptimisticReadStamp(existingStamp);
    }

    /**
     * @return true if the caller is holding a read-lock
     */
    public boolean isRead()
    {
        Long existingStamp = this.stamp.get();
        return existingStamp != null && StampedLock.isReadLockStamp(existingStamp);
    }

    /**
     * @return true if the caller is holding a write-lock
     */
    public boolean isWrite()
    {
        Long existingStamp = this.stamp.get();
        return existingStamp != null && StampedLock.isWriteLockStamp(existingStamp);
    }

    /**
     * Acquires an optimistic read-lock and runs a task. If an optimistic read-lock cannot be acquired, invokes
     * {@link #read(Callable) readLock(task)} instead.
     * <p>
     * {@code task} is guaranteed to be invoked <i>at least</i> once, but must be safe to invoke multiple times
     * as well. The return value must correspond to a local copy of the fields being read as there is no
     * guarantee that state won't change between the time the lock is released and the time that the value is
     * returned.
     *
     * @param <V>  the type of value returned by the task
     * @param task the task to run while holding the lock
     * @return the value returned by the task
     * @throws NullPointerException    if {@code task} is null
     * @throws WrappedCheckedException if any checked exceptions are thrown
     */
    public <V> V optimisticRead(Callable<V> task)
    {
        Long existingStamp = this.stamp.get();
        if (existingStamp != null)
        {
            if (StampedLock.isOptimisticReadStamp(existingStamp))
                return runWithOptimisticRead(task, existingStamp);
            if (StampedLock.isLockStamp(existingStamp))
                return runTask(task);
        }
        long stamp = lock.tryOptimisticRead();
        try
        {
            this.stamp.set(stamp);
            return runWithOptimisticRead(task, stamp);
        }
        finally
        {
            // There is nothing to unlock for optimistic reads
            this.stamp.set(existingStamp);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Acquires an optimistic read-lock and runs a task. If an optimistic read-lock cannot be acquired, invokes
     * {@link #read(Task) readLock(task)} instead.
     * <p>
     * {@code task} is guaranteed to be invoked <i>at least</i> once, but must be safe to invoke multiple times
     * as well. The return value must correspond to a local copy of the fields being read as there is no
     * guarantee that state won't change between the time the lock is released and the time that the value is
     * returned.
     *
     * @param task the task to run while holding the lock
     * @throws NullPointerException    if {@code task} is null
     * @throws WrappedCheckedException if any checked exceptions are thrown
     */
    public void optimisticRead(Task task)
    {
        optimisticRead(() ->
        {
            task.run();
            return null;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Acquires an optimistic read-lock and runs a task. If an optimistic read-lock cannot be acquired, invokes
     * {@link #read(Callable) readLock(task)} instead.
     * <p>
     * {@code task} is guaranteed to be invoked <i>at least</i> once, but must be safe to invoke multiple times
     * as well. The return value must correspond to a local copy of the fields being read as there is no
     * guarantee that state won't change between the time the lock is released and the time that the value is
     * returned.
     *
     * @param <V>   the type of value returned by the task
     * @param task  the task to run while holding the lock
     * @param stamp the optimistic read-lock to use
     * @return the value returned by the task
     * @throws NullPointerException    if {@code task} is null
     * @throws WrappedCheckedException if any checked exceptions are thrown
     */
    private <V> V runWithOptimisticRead(Callable<V> task, long stamp)
    {
        if (stamp != 0)
        {
            V result = runTask(task);
            if (lock.validate(stamp))
                return result;
        }
        return read(task);
    }

    /**
     * Acquires a read-lock, unless the caller already holds a read or write-lock. If the caller already holds a
     * lock, no lock is acquired or released.
     *
     * @return a read-lock as a resource
     */
    public CloseableLock read()
    {
        Long existingStamp = this.stamp.get();
        if (existingStamp != null && StampedLock.isLockStamp(existingStamp))
        {
            // Pre-existing read-lock or write-lock
            return ReentrantStampedLock::doNotUnlock;
        }
        // No lock, or optimistic read-lock
        long stamp = lock.readLock();
        this.stamp.set(stamp);
        return () ->
        {
            // Must re-read stamp value from ThreadLocal because tasks that invoke writeLock() may modify the
            // stamp value
            lock.unlockRead(this.stamp.get());
            this.stamp.set(existingStamp);
        };
    }

    /**
     * Runs a task while holding a read-lock. If the caller already holds a read or write-lock, no lock is
     * acquired or released.
     *
     * @param <V>  the type of value returned by the task
     * @param task the task to run while holding the lock
     * @return the value returned by the task
     * @throws NullPointerException    if {@code task} is null
     * @throws WrappedCheckedException if {@code task} throws a checked exception
     */
    public <V> V read(Callable<V> task)
    {
        try (CloseableLock ignored = read())
        {
            return runTask(task);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs a task while holding a read-lock. If the caller already holds a read or write-lock, no lock is
     * acquired or released.
     *
     * @param task the task to run while holding the lock
     * @throws NullPointerException    if {@code task} is null
     * @throws WrappedCheckedException if {@code task} throws a checked exception
     */
    public void read(Task task)
    {
        read(() ->
        {
            task.run();
            return null;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Acquires a write-lock, unless the caller already holds one. If the caller already holds a lock, no lock
     * is acquired or released.
     * <p>
     * If the caller holds a read-lock, an attempt is made to convert it into a write-lock. Conversions are not
     * guaranteed to be atomic; consequently, there is no guarantee that state won't change between the time the
     * read-lock is released and the write-lock is acquired. Callers must repeat any state checks to ensure that
     * they still hold.
     *
     * @return a write-lock as a resource
     */
    public CloseableLock write()
    {
        Long existingStamp = this.stamp.get();
        if (existingStamp == null)
            return noLockToWriteLock(null);
        if (StampedLock.isWriteLockStamp(existingStamp))
            return ReentrantStampedLock::doNotUnlock;
        if (!StampedLock.isReadLockStamp(existingStamp))
        {
            // optimistic read-lock
            return noLockToWriteLock(existingStamp);
        }
        // read-lock
        long writeLock = lock.tryConvertToWriteLock(existingStamp);
        if (writeLock == 0)
        {
            lock.unlockRead(existingStamp);
            writeLock = lock.writeLock();
        }
        this.stamp.set(writeLock);
        long finalWriteLock = writeLock;
        return () ->
        {
            // The returned stamp value is guaranteed to be a read-lock, but the stamp value may change.
            long readStamp = lock.tryConvertToReadLock(finalWriteLock);
            assert (readStamp != 0);
            this.stamp.set(readStamp);
        };
    }

    /**
     * Acquires a write-lock with no pre-existing lock.
     *
     * @param existingStamp the existing stamp
     * @return a write-lock as a resource
     */
    private CloseableLock noLockToWriteLock(Long existingStamp)
    {
        this.stamp.set(lock.writeLock());
        return () ->
        {
            lock.unlock(this.stamp.get());
            this.stamp.set(existingStamp);
        };
    }

    /**
     * Runs a task while holding a write-lock. If the caller already holds a lock, no lock is acquired or
     * released.
     * <p>
     * If the caller holds a read-lock, an attempt is made to convert it into a write-lock. Conversions are not
     * guaranteed to be atomic; consequently, there is no guarantee that state won't change between the time the
     * read-lock is released and the write-lock is acquired. Callers must repeat any state checks to ensure that
     * they still hold.
     *
     * @param <V>  the type of value returned by the task
     * @param task the task to run while holding the lock
     * @return the value returned by the task
     * @throws NullPointerException    if {@code task} is null
     * @throws WrappedCheckedException if {@code task} throws a checked exception
     */
    public <V> V write(Callable<V> task)
    {
        try (CloseableLock ignored = write())
        {
            return runTask(task);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs a task while holding a write-lock. If the caller already holds a lock, no lock is acquired or
     * released.
     * <p>
     * If the caller holds a read-lock, an attempt is made to convert it into a write-lock. Conversions are not
     * guaranteed to be atomic; consequently, there is no guarantee that state won't change between the time the
     * read-lock is released and the write-lock is acquired. Callers must repeat any state checks to ensure that
     * they still hold.
     *
     * @param task the task to run while holding the lock
     * @throws NullPointerException    if {@code task} is null
     * @throws WrappedCheckedException if {@code task} throws a checked exception
     */
    public void write(Task task)
    {
        write(() ->
        {
            task.run();
            return null;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Runs a task.
     *
     * @param <V>  the type of value returned by the task
     * @param task the task to run while holding the lock
     * @return the value returned by the task
     * @throws NullPointerException    if {@code task} is null
     * @throws WrappedCheckedException if {@code task} throws a checked exception
     */
    private <V> V runTask(Callable<V> task)
    {
        try
        {
            return task.call();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw WrappedCheckedException.wrap(e);
        }
    }
}
```

CloseableLock.java:

```
/**
 * Let the compiler know that releasing a lock does not throw any exceptions.
 */
public interface CloseableLock extends AutoCloseable
{
    @Override
    void close();
}
```

WrappedCheckedException:

```
import java.io.Serial;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

/**
 * A runtime exception dedicated to wrapping checked exceptions.
 */
public final class WrappedCheckedException extends RuntimeException
{
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    /**
     * Wraps an exception.
     *
     * @param message the detail message
     * @param cause   the exception to wrap
     * @throws NullPointerException if any of the arguments are null
     */
    private WrappedCheckedException(String message, Throwable cause)
    {
        super(message, cause);
        if (message == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("message may not be null");
        if (cause == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("cause may not be null");
    }

    /**
     * Wraps an exception.
     *
     * @param cause the exception to wrap
     * @throws NullPointerException if {@code cause} is null
     */
    private WrappedCheckedException(Throwable cause)
    {
        super(cause);
        if (cause == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("cause may not be null");
    }

    /**
     * Wraps any checked exceptions thrown by a callable.
     *
     * @param callable the task to execute
     * @param <V>      the type of value returned by {@code callable}
     * @return the value returned by {@code callable}
     * @throws NullPointerException if {@code callable} is null
     */
    public static <V> V wrap(Callable<V> callable)
    {
        try
        {
            return callable.call();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw WrappedCheckedException.wrap(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Wraps any checked exceptions thrown by a task.
     *
     * @param task the task to execute
     * @throws NullPointerException if {@code task} is null
     */
    public static void wrap(Task task)
    {
        try
        {
            task.run();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw WrappedCheckedException.wrap(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Wraps any checked exceptions thrown by a task. It rethrows the expected checked exceptions and wraps the
     * rest in a {@code WrappedCheckedException}.
     *
     * @param <E1>      a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param task      the task to execute
     * @param expected1 a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @throws NullPointerException if any of the arguments are null
     * @throws E1                   a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     */
    public static <E1 extends Exception> void wrap(Task task, Class<E1> expected1) throws E1
    {
        try
        {
            task.run();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (expected1.isInstance(e))
                throw expected1.cast(e);
            throw WrappedCheckedException.wrap(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Wraps any checked exceptions thrown by a task. It rethrows the expected checked exceptions and wraps the
     * rest in a {@code WrappedCheckedException}.
     *
     * @param <E1>      a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param <E2>      a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param task      the task to execute
     * @param expected1 a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param expected2 a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @throws NullPointerException if any of the arguments are null
     * @throws E1                   a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @throws E2                   a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     */
    public static <E1 extends Exception, E2 extends Exception> void wrap(Task task, Class<E1> expected1,
        Class<E2> expected2) throws E1, E2
    {
        try
        {
            task.run();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (expected1.isInstance(e))
                throw expected1.cast(e);
            if (expected2.isInstance(e))
                throw expected2.cast(e);
            throw WrappedCheckedException.wrap(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Wraps any checked exceptions thrown by a task. It rethrows the expected checked exceptions and wraps the
     * rest in a {@code WrappedCheckedException}.
     *
     * @param <E1>       a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param <E2>       a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param <E3>       a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param task       the task to execute
     * @param exception1 a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param exception2 a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param exception3 a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @throws NullPointerException if any of the arguments are null
     * @throws E1                   a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @throws E2                   a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @throws E3                   a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     */
    public static <E1 extends Exception, E2 extends Exception, E3 extends Exception> void wrap(
        Task task, Class<E1> exception1, Class<E2> exception2, Class<E3> exception3)
        throws E1, E2, E3
    {
        try
        {
            task.run();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (exception1.isInstance(e))
                throw exception1.cast(e);
            if (exception2.isInstance(e))
                throw exception2.cast(e);
            if (exception3.isInstance(e))
                throw exception3.cast(e);
            throw WrappedCheckedException.wrap(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Wraps any checked exceptions thrown by a task. It rethrows the expected checked exceptions and wraps the
     * rest in a {@code WrappedCheckedException}.
     *
     * @param <E1>      a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param <E2>      a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param <E3>      a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param <E4>      a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param task      the task to execute
     * @param expected1 a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param expected2 a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param expected3 a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param expected4 a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @throws NullPointerException if any of the arguments are null
     * @throws E1                   a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @throws E2                   a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @throws E3                   a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @throws E4                   a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     */
    public static <E1 extends Exception, E2 extends Exception, E3 extends Exception, E4 extends Exception>
    void wrap(Task task, Class<E1> expected1, Class<E2> expected2, Class<E3> expected3, Class<E4> expected4)
        throws E1, E2, E3, E4
    {
        try
        {
            task.run();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (expected1.isInstance(e))
                throw expected1.cast(e);
            if (expected2.isInstance(e))
                throw expected2.cast(e);
            if (expected3.isInstance(e))
                throw expected3.cast(e);
            if (expected4.isInstance(e))
                throw expected4.cast(e);
            throw WrappedCheckedException.wrap(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Wraps any checked exceptions thrown by a task. It rethrows the expected checked exceptions and wraps the
     * rest in a {@code WrappedCheckedException}.
     *
     * @param <E1>      a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param <E2>      a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param <E3>      a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param <E4>      a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param <E5>      a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param task      the task to execute
     * @param expected1 a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param expected2 a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param expected3 a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param expected4 a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @param expected5 a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @throws NullPointerException if any of the arguments are null
     * @throws E1                   a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @throws E2                   a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @throws E3                   a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @throws E4                   a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     * @throws E5                   a checked exception that may be thrown by the task
     */
    public static <E1 extends Exception, E2 extends Exception, E3 extends Exception, E4 extends Exception,
        E5 extends Exception> void wrap(Task task, Class<E1> expected1, Class<E2> expected2, Class<E3> expected3,
        Class<E4> expected4, Class<E5> expected5) throws E1, E2, E3, E4, E5
    {
        try
        {
            task.run();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (expected1.isInstance(e))
                throw expected1.cast(e);
            if (expected2.isInstance(e))
                throw expected2.cast(e);
            if (expected3.isInstance(e))
                throw expected3.cast(e);
            if (expected4.isInstance(e))
                throw expected4.cast(e);
            if (expected5.isInstance(e))
                throw expected5.cast(e);
            throw WrappedCheckedException.wrap(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Wraps an exception, unless it is a {@code RuntimeException}.
     *
     * @param t the exception to wrap
     * @return the updated exception
     * @throws NullPointerException if {@code t} is null
     */
    public static RuntimeException wrap(Throwable t)
    {
        if (t instanceof RuntimeException re)
            return re;
        if (t instanceof ExecutionException ee)
            return wrap(ee.getCause());
        return new WrappedCheckedException(t);
    }

    /**
     * Wraps an exception, unless it is a {@code RuntimeException}.
     *
     * @param message the detail message of the WrappedCheckedException
     * @param t       the exception to wrap
     * @return the updated exception
     * @throws NullPointerException if {@code t} is null
     */
    public static RuntimeException wrap(String message, Throwable t)
    {
        if (t instanceof RuntimeException re)
            return re;
        if (t instanceof ExecutionException ee)
            return wrap(message, ee.getCause());
        return new WrappedCheckedException(message, t);
    }

    /**
     * A {@link Callable} without a return value.
     */
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface Task
    {
        /**
         * Runs the task.
         *
         * @throws Exception if unable to compute a result
         */
        void run() throws Exception;
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
ReentrantStampedLock lock = new ReentrantStampedLock();

// try-with-resource syntax
try (CloseableLock ignored = lock.readLock())
{
  doSomething();
  // read-lock automatically released
}

// Lambda syntax
lock.optimisticReadLock(() -> doSomething());
```